# Postgres Match All array values to same column with and condition ---updated

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have table table_a with following columns

```
id  event_id
1   101
1   102
1   103
2   105
2   103
2   106
```

I and to search (101, 103) with and conditions similar to IN query with OR condition

For example id 1 match both for 101 and 103 event_id;

For this I write following query but it not working.

```
select * from table_a where event_id = ALL(ARRAY[101,103]);
```

**UPDATED---------------------------**
And I have another problem

let say id is foreign of another table event_categories having relation like this.

```
id      parent_id
101     null
102     101
103     101
104     null
105     104
```

so I want to fetch records from table_a based on AND with parent event category, OR within sub event categories of that parent.

For example 101, 104  with AND
  102, 103 within OR of 101

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question (and mark one of the answers as accepted, so that this question is marked as resolved)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260956/postgres-match-all-array-values-to-same-column-with-and-condition)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to aggregate all event_ids for a single ID:

```
select id
from table_a
group by id
having array_agg(event_id) @> array[101,103];
```

The `@>` is the contains operator so it checks if the array of all event_ids contains the array with those two IDs.

That will return any id that has *at least* the two event 101 and 103 (which is what you asked for in your question).

If you would like to find those IDs that have **exactly** those two event_ids (which your sample data does not contain) you could use:

```
select id
from table_a
group by id
having array_agg(distinct event_id order by event_id) = array[101,103];
```

Note that the order of the elements in the array matters for the `=` operator (unlike the "contains" `@>` operator)

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM YourTable
WHERE event_id IN(101,103)
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct event_id) = 2
```